# Angular 5 application works with prod build, but not the dev build

Tags: angular

I've got an angular 5 application, all of the polyfills are enabled to work with IE, and I'm targeting es5 and not es6. Everything works fine with a prod build, but with the dev build it fails to get past 'loading...' in IE. No errors appear in the console. What is different with ng serve --prod vs. just a ng serve that is preventing IE from running the application?

Comment: have you tried with other browsers (for instance chrome)? `ng serve --prod` IIRC also enable AOT.

Comment: chrome has worked fine the whole time, with just ng serve and ng serve --prod. It was just IE that would not work with a simple ng serve. After doing ng serve --aot=true IE started to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cli doc says

> ES2015 support.
>
> To build in ES2015 mode, edit ./tsconfig.json to use "target": "es2015" (instead of es5).
>
> This will cause application TypeScript and Uglify be output as ES2015, and third party libraries to be loaded through the es2015 entry in package.json if available.
>
> Be aware that JIT does not support ES2015 and so you should build/serve your app with --aot. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7797 for details.

are you sure about the `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: Thanks for the info, good stuff to know. However, after changing tsconfig.ts to have target es2015 instead of es5 it is still not working in IE. ng serve -aot also does not do the trick

Comment: what I think I'll do is just bite the bullet and do a prod build when I need to test locally for IE stuff and make a new environment ts file for prod build using test api calls... ng serve --prod -o --environment=EnvironmentForIETesting

Comment: I changed my tsconfig back to es5 (I may be using an older version of angular cli?) and then ran ng serve --aot=true rather than just ng serve --aot and it works. Strange little differences...